# How to deploy an app to mobile after adding AndroidManifest.xml to Project

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, kde-plasma

My problem is, that I can't seem to deploy my app to my phone (galaxy s4) or the emulator anymore, after adding the AndroidManifest.xml to the project.

I have been working on this app for 1 or 2 days, never had a problem testing it on my phone. I wanted to add the App Icon and change the app display name and found out that it had to be done over the AndroidManifest.xml file. So after finally finding where to add it in the QtCreator, I added an Icon and changed the name. When I click deploy, it loads and then the bar turns red, without ANY error messages or nothing. It just goes red full and then goes away. Even the warnings from build are not even showing.

I hope you guys can help me, this is my first question, so if I forgot any information or asked the question wrong, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You need dirqml2sdk debugger libaries (if your OS is windows). You can download it from [here](http://www.facebook.com/nahom.wosen).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have KDE, do I still need it?